# IE8 doesnt like my jQuery

Tags: jquery

Can anyone see any reason why IE8 might not run this jQuery?

```
        $("#slid").toggle(
            function() {
                $("#Silver").animate({top: "25px"}, 200);
            },
            function() {
                $("#Silver").animate({top: "89px"}, 200);
            }
        );
```

It runs the first function but ignores the 2nd `top: "89px"` and ideas? Or a better way the same toggle effect can be achieveD?

Comment: IE is like that; Doesn't like developers :/

Comment: What you have works, another event handler attached to this perhaps? http://jsfiddle.net/HkBku/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested it in IE8 and this code works:

**CSS**

```
#Silver {top:89px;position:absolute;}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="slid">click</div>
<div id="Silver">hi</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("#slid").toggle(
    function() {
        $("#Silver").animate({top: "25px"}, 200);
    },
    function() {
        $("#Silver").animate({top: "89px"}, 200);
    }
);
```

You can have a look at the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/kr6t3/4/

Adding `position:absolute` to the element in the CSS works in IE8 and FF3.6.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem with IE and toggle. Can't remember how I solved it. But With IE I've noticed it like class selectors better than id selectors. Try using class instead of ID.

I tried :

```
$("#slid").toggle(
            function() {
                $("#Silver").html("hello");
            },
            function() {
                $("#Silver").html("hi");
            }
        );
```

seems to be working fine with ie6 don't know about 8.